# Decomposition of vector bundles on the inertia stack of a DM stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be a tame DM stack over $\mathbb{C}.$ Let $IX$ denote the inertia stack of $X.$ Let $K(IX)$ denote the Grothendieck group of vector bundles on $IX.$ By the discussion on page 20 of [Toen's paper "Riemann-Roch Theorems for Deligne-Mumford Stacks",](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803076) there is a map

$$\rho: K(IX) \to K(IX)_\mathbb{C}.$$

Let $V$ be a vector bundle on $IX$. Then $\rho$ maps $V$ to $\sum_{\zeta \in \mu_\infty} \zeta V^{(\zeta)},$ where $\mu_\infty$ is the union of all $\mu_n$ for integers $n \geq 1,$ i.e., $\mu_\infty$ consists of all roots of unity, and $V^{(\zeta)}$ is the eigenbundle of $V$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\zeta.$

Is $\sum_{\zeta \in \mu_\infty} \zeta V^{(\zeta)}$ a finite sum?

Edit: The map $\rho$ is well-defined if the sum above is finite. So the question is whether $\rho$ is always well-defined.

Comment: Is $V$ of finite rank?

Comment: @Qfwfq I would assume $V$ is of finite rank on each connected component of $IX.$